# DVD to MKV conversion remains incomplete

Tags: video, dvd, matroska, handbrake

I have a DVD with a menu, multiple VOB files, one audio and one subtitle track. It is a DVD of a TV show, so has about 9 separate episodes accessible from a menu, and is about 3 hours 20 mins long.

I want to merge it into one single Matroska file, but when I encode it, I always end up with a clip that's just one hour long, and a fraction of the chapters included (there are 18 total, and only 3 in random order get written, the same 3 each time I try).

I've used [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr) and a free tool called video.net. In both cases, I end up with the same result. I've also tried copying the entire DVD folder locally for faster reads, to no avail.
Is there a configuration problem with Handbrake?

I'm hoping the solution here isn't 'go and download commercial tool x that costs a bomb and whose trial version will just encode 5 minutes worth of video' - I've seen enough ads for WinXDVD while searching for results and I don't want to dump a load of cash for what is a one time job.

Answer (score 0):

[MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/) can merge all chapters in a loaded DVD and export it to MOV/MP4 file. It is free and is still widely used within the video post production industry so you can trust it to be a good shot at trying to rip your DVD.

After your DVD is inserted, simply click on 'File > Open DVD' and you will be given options if you want to export specific chapters or the whole thing. It can also load individual VOB files for conversion if you wish.

You won't be able to output to MKV but you can still make a high quality MOV out of it and then convert that to MKV if you need.

Comment: Tried it, installed the required older version of Quicktime Alternate, but every time it crashes after encoding about 2%.

Answer (score 0):

There are many free tools can rip DVDs to MKV. The reason why your files are shorter than the original probably because your files are not ripped completely. It will be better to see the list of the ripped files to check if there are the same with your original file. If not, you need to change a different tool.

PS: Free tools are often limited with functions. If you want to keep the quality or length of your files, you may consider a paid tool. After all, this kind of DVD tools is not one time thing. You may use it in the future. Just a suggestion for you.

Comment: //After all, this kind of DVD tools is not one time thing
That's just it, it _is_ a one time thing. I don't use DVDs at all and this just happens to be a rare Indian show that can't be got anywhere else.